# How can I add an array of arguments inside my rsync call inside a script?

Tags: bash, rsync, bash-script, array

I want to copy a folder to another location, while excluding some specific files

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$2" ]
then
    source=$(readlink -f $1)
    destination=$(readlink -f $2)
else
    printf "\nProper syntax: my_copy source_folder destination_folder\n"
        exit
fi


params=(
    --exclude='.git'
    --exclude='deploy'
    --exclude='app/config/database.php'
    --exclude='app/config/config.php'
)


cd $source
rsync " -a ${params[@]} $source/* $destination"
```

When I run my script, I get this error:

```
rsync: link_stat "-a --exclude=.git" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rsync -a "${params[@]}" $source/ $destination` if not work then try `echo rsync -a "${params[@]}" $source/ $destination| sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what's happening change the `rsync` command to an `echo` command first.

```
$ echo "rsync \" -a ${params[@]} $source/* $destination\""
```

#### Potential Fixes

I would change that line to this instead:

```
$ rsync -a "${params[@]}" "$source/"* "$destination"
```

Comment: why multi source and destination there ?

Comment: @RahulPatil - not following your question

Comment: This also gives me the same error. The funny thing is that when I echo the command, and copy-paste it to the terminal, it works as it should, but if I remove the echo from the line I get an `./deploy: line 49: rsync " -a --exclude=.git: command not found` error

Comment: @Loupax - get rid of the double quotes around the arguments. I think that was the original issue. See update. You can try it with and without the $(echo ...)

Comment: That was it after all :)

Comment: @Loupax - yeah they can be annoying little buggers. 8-)

Comment: First script, feels good :)

Comment: @Loupax - good looking first script. Good use of arrays, thinking the right way!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd written this:

```
rsync " -a $params $source/* $destination"
```

then the `rsync` command would be getting a single string as its argument, because all the variables are expanded inside double quotes. For example, if `$params` is `--exclude=.git`, `$source` is `/somewhere` and `$destination` is `/elsewhere` then the argument would be

```
 -a --exclude=.git /somewhere/* /elsewhere
```

There's an added wrinkle: `"${params[@]}"` splits the array into separate parameters. The text before `${params[@]}` is attached to the first array element and the text after `${params[@]}` is attached to the last array element. So `rsync` is called with four parameters:

```
 -a --exclude=.git
--exclude=deploy
--exclude=app/config/database.php
--exclude=app/config/config.php /somewhere/* /elsewhere
```

Each parameter must be a separate double-quoted string. You need the double quotes to protect the expansion of the variables in case they contain whitespace or wildcard characters. For the array expanded with `${NAME[@]}`, `"${NAME[@]}"` places each element in a separate parameter. The spaces that separate elements, and the characters that are intended to function as wildcards, must remain unquoted.

```
rsync -a "${params[@]}" -- "$source"/* "$destination"
```

This excludes dot files directly under `$source`, because of the `/`. To copy files under `$source` to files with the same name under `$destination`, just put a slash after the path to the source directory.

```
rsync -a "${params[@]}" -- "$source/" "$destination"
```